# use facet_wrap for geom_point overlay with a constant base layer

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to build a plot where I highlight different subset of data over the top of the distribution of the whole sample.

I display the distribution of the entire sample using geom_hex, to show where most of the data is, and then for a subset, I plot the actual locations of the data points on top. I want to use facet_wrap to do this for a number of subsets. However, my current code reproduces the plot for only the subset of data (i.e. geom_hex only shows the distribution of the subset of data, not the entire sample). Is it possible to use facet_wrap in this way?

```
set.seed(123)
n = 1000
df = data.frame(x = rnorm(n),
                y = rnorm(n),
                group = sample(letters[1:2], n, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, col = group)) + 
  geom_hex() +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(~group)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It is to use the transform function within the ggplot call to remove information from the grouping variable.

You need to add a col aesthetic in to that call (even if it not being used). Otherwise it doesn't work, which seems a bit hacky. So I would welcome alternative answers.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, col = group)) + 
+   geom_hex(data = transform(df, group = NULL), colour = "grey85") +
+   geom_point() + 
+   facet_grid(~group)
```